# Why my compare operator is not comparing my point length and double value?

Tags: c++, operators, logical-operators

I create new operator to compare my point vector length and double value. I have condition to tolerate different which is less than 0.01.
When i using this operator to compare my Point and my double value (both values after approaching are same) but the operator == is not returning true.

```
class Point {
private:
    double x, y, z;
public:
    Point() { x = y = z = 0.0; }
    Point(double v) { x = y = z = v; }
    Point(double x, double y, double z){
        this->x = x; this->y = y; this->z = z;
    }
    double getLength(){
        return sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2));
    }
    friend const bool operator== (double &d, Point &v);
};

double approach(double num){
    return floor(num*100)/100;
}

const bool operator== (const double &d, Point &v){
    return (approach(d) == approach(v.getLength()));
}

int main()
{
    Point p1(3,4,1);
    cout << p1.getLength() << endl; // 5.09902
    cout << approach(p1.getLength()) << endl;
    cout << approach(5.091) << endl;
    if(5.091 == p1)
        cout << "True";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I tested it in gcc it outputs `"True"`. https://wandbox.org/permlink/KzPHzxaj6AOGhYh3

Comment: It also outputs True with clang

Comment: I also get "True" output with `clang-cl`, along with this: **warning : comparing floating point with == or != is unsafe [-Wfloat-equal]**.

Comment: Ohh, so that should be compiler fault. In CodeBloacks i dont see "true", but in VS everything is working correct, Thank you guys :)

Comment: It's possible that with gcc on 32 bit x86 systems, this will not print True, due to [bug 323](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323), where it has excess precision in some cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be reproduced on gcc with 32 bit Intel architecture, without optimization.
Here is an example of it happening:
[compiler explorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/bx0EZO).

This is due to the infamous [323 bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323) of gcc, which struggles to work with Intel's 80 bit floating point registers, which are wider than the 64 bits of type `double`. Some of the values end up in the 80-bit register, and some values in the 64-bit memory value.

In your case, `approach(d)` is called first, and then get spilled to memory when `v.getLength()` is called. The value of `approach(v.getLength())`, on the other hand, is not getting spilled and gets all of register's 80-bit precision.

When you compare an 80-bit accurate value, and a truncated 64-bit  value, the comparison result is `false`.

A possible solution is to avoid the division by 100 in `approach()`, since it is what introduces the extra bits. Instead, you can try:

```
static constexpr double magnitude = 100.0;
const bool operator== (double d, const Point &v){
    return floor(d * magnitude) == floor(v.getLength() * magnitude));
}
```